# ActionScript 3: Array length issue

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

HI this my code, am unable to get the length of the array.

```
package com.mypro {


    public class MyEve {

        public var process:Array ;


        public function MyEve() {
            // constructor code
            this.process = new Array();
            trace("this.process " + this.process)
            this.process["CONFIG_XML_LOADING"]          = 'Configuration XML Loading';
            this.process['CONFIG_XML_LOADED']           = 'Configuration XML Loaded';


            trace("this.process +++ " + this.process.length)

        }

    }
}
```

OutPut

```
// Trace
this.process 
this.process +++ 0
```

Comment: You shouldn't use an Array as a HashMap. Use a dictionnary.

Comment: The resulting 0 is giving you the length of the array.

Comment: but this is an associate array. the key is CONFIG_XML_LOADED

Comment: The actionscript Array class is not intended to be used that way, as others have said. You should look into using a dictionary, or read up on using objects for associative arrays.

Answer (score 4):

While it's possible to use an array as a associative array, the length property won't work - it'll just return 0. You need to calculate the length yourself using either a for..in or a for each:

for..in:

```
var len:int = 0;
for ( var key:String in this.process )
    len++;
```

for each:

```
var len:int = 0;
for each( var value:String in this.process )
    len++;
```

as pointed out before though, it's probably better if you use Object (String key) or Dictionary (Object key) for this sort of thing.

Comment: note, you can't really get the length of a dictionary either. So, you'll still have to loop over the keys (or values) to count them.  In my code, I have a "sizeOfDictionary(Dictionary)" function that does just that

Answer (score 1):

You should use an Object to create an associative array.

```
public var process:Object;
public function MyEve() {
    // constructor code
    this.process = new Object();
    trace("this.process " + this.process)
    this.process["CONFIG_XML_LOADING"]          = 'Configuration XML Loading';
    this.process['CONFIG_XML_LOADED']           = 'Configuration XML Loaded';


    trace("this.process +++ " + this.process.length)

}
```

Read [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_4.html) for more information.

---

EDIT:
Ah, yes. As divillysausages pointed out you were trying to get the length. That isn't directly possible for Objects. You can, however, iterate through an Object's properties with the for...in loop, making it trivial to count each property of the object. [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f5b) and [here](http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/02/subtle-change-in-forin-loops-for-actionscript-3.cfm) are good examples of how to use it.

Comment: without getting pedantic, his question was on how to find the length of the array, and this doesn't solve it. I agree than an Object is best to use in this situation though

Answer (score 0):

See [[] array access](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access) from AS3 Reference.

You must use integer value for arrays or instead `Array` use `Object` or `Dictionary`

Comment: While it's better to use an Object or a Dictionary, this is a valid use of the Array

Comment: @divillysausages Although technically correct, I'm not sure if I'd call this use of the array class valid.  Since array extends Object, he is already doing what most have suggested; and the reason 'length' doesn't work is because he isn't using the "Array" specific extension of "Object" to add or remove elements.